# StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden',

Tags: onedrive, azure-ad-msal

We are trying to connect the OneDrive Graph API from wpf application, provided the client ID and other required elements. But we are getting the following error response upon calling the following code.

```
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

In the response we are getting the following forbidden error message.

> StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>     request-id: b35f6735-a762-4924-9d0b-43223423
>     client-request-id: b35f6735-a762-4924-9d0b-123123
>     x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South India","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_3","ADSiteName":"INS"}}
>     Duration: 293.2425
>     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
>     Cache-Control: private
>     Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2019 15:44:22 GMT
>     Content-Type: application/json
>   }}
>   Please let us to get out from the error.

We have tried by providing all the needed permissions to make it work.

Comment: How did you get the access token?

Comment: Using the following code to get the token.

authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle) // optional, used to center the browser on the window
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();