# Graph API StatusCode: 403,

Tags: .net, azure, graph

I have been trying to get access token from below code.  and have been using this token to get data from Graph REST API. While passing this token, I can not receive data and it says 403 Error

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
           .Create("")
           .WithTenantId("fd49eed930e2db05de")
           .WithClientSecret("W9gF..e7JJ_q37Q9z_E3")
           .Build();

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        string token = authResult.AccessToken;


        await CallWebApiAndProcessResultASync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", token, Display);

    }

    public static async Task CallWebApiAndProcessResultASync(string webApiUrl, string accessToken, Action<JObject> processResult)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            using (HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var defaultRequestHeaders = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
                if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
                {
                    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                }
                defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(webApiUrl);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    processResult(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to call the Web Api: {response.StatusCode}");
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Content: {content}");
                }
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Display(JObject result)
    {
        foreach (JProperty child in result.Properties().Where(p => !p.Name.StartsWith("@")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{child.Name} = {child.Value}");
        }
    }
```

Please note that I am admin in Azure.

[Reference Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257472/statuscode-403-reasonphrase-forbidden/63405954?noredirect=1#comment112118862_63405954)

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the permissions on your AAD application against to Microsoft graph API?

According the document of [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), we need one of following permission to call this API:

```
User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions) to match the permission name to the scope name.